# No control over the browser version being used on containers for our test?

Tags: zalenium

Browser comes with selenium image. For different browser version, need to pull different docker image.
Suppose I want to run my tests on Chrome Browser's 73.0.3683.86 version, then Can we consider an option of specifying the browser version while starting zalenium ? i.e. docker run --rm -ti --name zalenium -p 4444:4444 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /tmp/videos:/home/seluser/videos --privileged dosel/zalenium start --timeZone "Asia/Kolkata" --screenWidth 1280 --screenHeight 720 --chromeVersion "73.0.3683.86"
It should pull the version runtime in image.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not implemented. Zalenium is open source, consider sending a pull request to add that feature.